# Facebook Graph API - User doesn't have enough permissions to load insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm seeing this error for a page with this endpoint:

12345566/feed?fields=insights.metric(post_impressions_unique,post_impressions)

and I'm seeing this error:  User doesn't have enough permissions to load insights

I've added the following permissions: `read_insights` `pages_read_engagement`, etc that is required according to the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v11.0/insights) but when I contact Facebook Developer support they say I have to add it at to Granular Scope.... how do I do this? I've attached a picture showing what the token debugger shoes for this Page Access Token permissions [image]

Answer (score 0):

I did have a similar issue on some of my pages. I did reach the Facebook's support on the matter.
TL;DR use `/published_posts` instead of `/feed`

Facebook's support full reply:

> I have investigated this and I have a solution for you. Instead of using the `/feed` endpoint for the Page, please use the `/published_posts` endpoint instead.
>
> The 'feed' for a page includes posts made by other Users/Pages when they tag your Page. When you try to access the insights for these posts made by other accounts, we run into the issue that this access token does not have the permissions to view those insights.
>
> The 'published_posts' endpoint only includes posts made by the page itself, so you will be able to retrieve the insights using this.
>
> Thank you for flagging this to us. I will see if there are improvements that could be made to our documentation or error messaging to improve the experience of other developers.

Comment: Incase this helps someone else, I ran into a similar issue hitting the {page_id}/tagged endpoint.  I was testing an app in development and, for some of the mentions returned, I didn't have permission to view insights.  I was able to limit the api call to only get the last 2 mentions, which were users of my app, and that resolved the error for me.